# Xubuntu - screen flipped upside down

Tags: xubuntu, display

I was trying to fix a different problem when suddenly my screen switched upside down - rotated 180 degrees. How can I fix this. I'm on Xubuntu 14.10 and a Dell Latitude e6420.

Comment: Did you use `xrandr` in your attempt to fix? Try: `xrandr --output <screen_name> --rotate normal` if so, but you will have to find out your screen name from the command `xrandr`, look for "connected". (And you will probably hurt your neck doing so ;))

Comment: just `xrandr -o normal` fixed it for me. No I haven't used this command before, I must've hit some hot key?!

Comment: Go for it. I don't know what has happened, but I was playing with screen resolutions trying to fix screen getting out of bounds; (where virtual display is larger than physical display). Again having occurred by inadvertently hitting some wrong key combo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, the screen settings (`xrandr`) must have changed to "inverted" while you were trying to fix things.

You can fix it by running the command:

```
xrandr --output <screen_name> --rotate normal
```

or, (easyer) by simply loging out and back in :)

Answer (score 13):

Even easier : `xrandr -o normal`

Comment: (-: ʇxǝʇ pǝddᴉlɟ ǝɥʇ ǝʇsɐd-ʎdoɔ ʇ,uop ʎlsnoᴉʌqO
lɐɯɹou o- ɹpuɐɹx   :ǝɔuǝɹǝɟǝɹ ǝɹnʇnɟ ɹoℲ

Answer (score 0):

I just physically rotated my screen, Ubuntu 17.10 probably has some rotating sensors. Probably Gnome tablet program is active.
It could be same in the xubuntu 14.10 ! 
Once it was fixed in the needed rotation I locked the orientation.
Hope it helps someone.